# How to solve $y''=y+y'$ implicitly?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences

I have vector ODE like this.
$$y''=y+y'$$
I want to solve this numerically.

To solve explicitly,
iterarion formula is like this.
$$\frac{y_{n+1}-2y_n+y_{n-1}}{k^2}=y_n+\frac{y_{n+1}-y_{n-1}}{2k}$$
However, due to coefficient of my equation,
this iteration will be unstable.

So I want to use **implicit** method.
How to construct implicit scheme for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use Runge-Kutta for that equation? Since we have more than one method to solve such ODE. For instance, we can put $u=y'$, which lead us to the system of ODEs
$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
y' &=& u \\
u'  &=& u + y
\end{array}
$$
Or one has 
$$
W' = f(W,t)
$$
where $W(t)=( y(t), u(t) )$, $f =(f_1,f_2)$ and 
$$
f_1(W,t) = u(t),~~~
f_2(W,t) = u(t) + y(t).
$$
Then we can solve $W'=f(W,t)$ by using Runge-Kutta method. (You also need an initial condition, e.g. $y(0)=y_0$ and $y'(0) = y_1$, or in vectorform we have $W(0) = (y_0, y_1)$ ).

Edit: From the derived vector equation $W'=f(W,t)$ we can also use implicit schemes for time-advance.